# Can't list source using debug in ruby 1.8

Tags: ruby, debugging, ruby-debug, ruby-1.8

I have a very simple ruby program (`tmp.rb`) I'm trying to debug:

```
puts "a"
puts "b"
puts "c"
require "debug"
puts "d"
puts "d"
puts "e"
```

When I run it, it enters the debugger interactive mode:

```
a
b
c
Debug.rb
Emacs support available.

tmp.rb:5:
(rdb:1)
```

However, if I try to read the source-code, I get this message:

```
(rdb:1) l
[0, 9] in tmp.rb
No sourcefile available for tmp.rb
```

Am I doing something wrong?